# CRM 2011 which fields are being used?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm developing against MS CRM 2011. And I find out there are a lot of pain points including borderline broken, half arsed LINQ support.

That aside the latest one has to do with a lot of built-in fields that's been hidden away, deprecated and/or unused as far as the user is concerned. However from developer's perspective, we have no idea that these fields are deprecated. The context generated by crm util still generates these properties. So what ends up happening is that developers code against properties/relationship/entities that has been deprecated on a number of occassion.

So now the question is, is there a way to interrogate the crm services for a list of fields/properties that aren't in any form for **every** entity? What more is there a way to interrogate the crm services for all unused entities (for lack of a better word). These could be entities that are orphaned, hasn't been updated in a while and/or empty etc.

I hoping with such a list the developers will know what to look out for as opposed to coding blindly against the crm context, which has been a source of frustration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I don't think you'd want to just generate code for fields that are on forms - I use "hidden" fields for flags all the time.

There is a way to make crmsvcutil generate only the entities you want:

http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html

Sounds like you are a bit frustrated, but don't give up quite yet.  There are definitely architectural decisions that I question, but all of the plumbing that I don't have to write makes up for it.  Dynamics CRM is like any other technology, but I love it more than I hate it. :)

Comment: Thanks Josh, I need to study that post some more, but it looks like it's leading down the right path. I still need to figure out come convention to limit the generated entities somehow. Is there a way to flag properties/fields as obsolete/unused etc - like you can in code?

Comment: Not that I know of. I haven't personally customized crmsvcutil yet. However, I wonder if a post-processor of some sort could read your obsolete fields from a custom xml file and apply those Attributes to the Properties in the generated cs file? I found this with a quick search: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.asp

Comment: If you still want to find out which fields are on the form, just saw this:  http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2011/10/tool-update-searchable-property-updater.html

Answer (score 1):

I've not been able to find much which would allow you to do this, at least not in CRM 4 (which is the version I'm using).  None of that stuff seems to be documented anywhere.  I did write a query based off of [this guy's post](http://www.crmconsult.info/2011/09/crm-report-for-entity-and-attribute.html) which let me filter out most of the unused fields, but there was a lot of picking through the fields in the LocalizedLabelView to get what I wanted, and even then it wasn't easy.  It's probably even harder now in CRM 2011 since you can have multiple forms per entity.

Comment: I hate this product with a passion. It feels like it was created with little regard to sound architecture or best practices.

Comment: CRM 2011 is a DREAM compared to the last few versions.  I know how you feel though.  Considering the NEXT MAJOR VERSION will be the FIRST (!) to run on browsers other than IE, it's pretty hard to defend.  IMO it only is where it is in the marketplace because of its Outlook integration.

Comment: @Alwyn I share your pain. I've heard scary stories about CRM 4 so supposedly we're the lucky ones. I disagree... On the other hand, it's a narrow area and it's relatively easy to gain expert level (we're talking major pay for minor work). Not a fortnight passes between me considering going postal in Redmont...   :)